# Bulk search in MongoDB with Regex

Tags: sql, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am facing issue with Bulk search in mongodb with Regex.

In SQL we achieve this bulk search by join with accounts\subject table using Like operator in on condition. But in Mongo we were not able to achieve this. We did explore the option of Lookup aggregation in pipeline, but in vain. Regex in Mongo query has to be hard-coded as a literal .Dynamic or field values are not supported.

So far, we have only one approach of querying individual items one by one. But I am looking for efficient approach.

Please let us know if there are any other ways to achieve this in Mongo Db..

For e.g., from the below table,  we must search for all the values in the Search Value column and results for individual matches should be mapped to the respective source report numbers.
Also, all searches are wild card searches. For e.g., if the account number is 12345, we will have to search for *12345*.

```
Example :

    Report Num  Search By       Search Value
    MER-1ABC    Account Number  1234567
    MER-1ABC    Name            QWERTY POIUYT
    MER-1ABC    Name            QWERTY
  
I search for '1234567 or QWERTY POIUYT or QWERTY'
Let say result is "Stack Overflow is good"

Final Result
Key                            Value
MER-1ABC           "Stack Overflow is good"
MER-1ABC           "Stack Overflow is good" 
MER-1ABC           "Stack Overflow is good"
```

Comment: Could you add some examples of the documents and the expected result?

Comment: @RubénVega : Added example and result above

Comment: I'm sorry, but It is not clear to me yet... Could you provide the JSON documents, and what you expect to get, with you query also un JSON.